# How to force a method's return type to be inferred as a non-dynamic type when it is passed a dynamic argument

Tags: c#, dynamic, type-inference

Why does the following code infer var to dynamic? Additionally, is there a way to write a method(or encapsulate logic in general, doesn't have to be a method) that returns a value with a statically known (non-dynamic) type when it has been passed 1 or more dynamic arguments(inputs)?

```
public static T CastDynamicParam<T>(dynamic value)
{
    T result = value;
    return result;
}

public static T CastStaticParam<T>(T value)
{
    return value;
}

public static int CastNonGenericDynamicParam(dynamic value)
{
    return (int)value;
}

public static int CastNonGenericStaticParam(int value)
{
    return value;
}

//Why do these infer as dynamic?
dynamic d = 10;
var inferredToDynamic1 = CastDynamicParam<int>(d); 
var inferredToDynamic2 = CastStaticParam<int>(d);
var inferredToDynamic3 = CastNonGenericDynamicParam(d);
var inferredToDynamic4 = CastNonGenericStaticParam(d);
```

Comment: Use an explicit cast or declare using the actual type (i.e. do not infer the type).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight It's not even necessary to cast, if you declare it as `int` it works, but the behavior is weird...

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir That's why I wrote "or declare using the actual type" :-)

Comment: Indeed it is wierd. I mean that dynamic can match `int CastDynamicParam (int value)` is not odd. But that it comes out as a dynamic at the end (rather then int) is odd.

Comment: My best guess is currently that Dynamic breaks the type check so heavily, something goes "bump" in the Compiler. And this why what is actually interpredet by the compiler is soemthing like `CastDynamicParam<dynamic>(dynamic d)`. We agree that it propably should not be doing that. But it does.

Comment: @JonathonChase: Now that you linked it, I too think it is a Duplicate of that.

Comment: @Christopher Glad you agree ;)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton: Having multiple people agree it is a duplicate is the first step to close it as "Duplicate". If the same behavior happens with non-generic functions, that would explain it all.

Comment: The linked duplicate question does explain the first part, but it doesn't really give any suggestions on how to work around it.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I did notice this in the answer: "At least one argument of the optional argument-list has compile-time type dynamic and the primary-expression does not have a delegate type.". This led me to the realization that you could do something along the lines of: `public class Cast<T> { public static Func<dynamic, T> Call = value => (T)value; }` which is the sort of thing that I was looking for.